# ArcGIS dissolve analysis output issues in geoserver wfs/ PostGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, geoserver, wfs, dissolve

I have an ArcGIS dissolve analysis output (parcel data) that needs to be loaded on PostGIS and published as a  wfs from geoserver. The issue is that the ArcGIS dissolve output shapefile, although can be loaded to Postgres (PostGIS ) and published using geoserver, but attribute information (such as parcel id, address etc) cannot be fetched in the published parcel wfs. I have noticed that this is the case only with data that has been geoprocessed using dissolve analysis tool in ArcGIS. I have tried both multipart and no-multipart options while dissolving but with no luck. Any idea why this is so?